# How to perform complex calculations in python by using data from excel

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, graph, data-analysis

I have data in excel which contains 25 sensor values.

Each sensor has `ES_0_BME680_TEMP`, `ES_0_BME680_RH` values and for the next sensor its values are `ES_1_BME680_TEMP`, `ES_2_BME680_RH`, ...etc.

For each sensor I have to calculate the following and display in graphs.

```
ph20 = 611.2*exp((17.625*df[ES_0_BME680_TEMP])/(243.12+df[ES_0_BME680_TEMP]))

aH=(ES_0_BME680_RH /100)*(ph20/(461.52*(ES_0_BME680_TEMP+273.15)))*1000

LN=LN(((aH/1000)*461.52*(ES_0_BME680_TEMP+273.15))/(0.5*611.2))

T_tar=(LN*243.12)/(17.625-LN)
```

Please help me with the code.

Comment: could you provide an example of your data in pd.Dataframe please

Comment: the data I have is in excel, with a mixture of int and float values. I have 25 sensors and each sensor has this columns
 'ES_0_BME680_PRESS',
 'ES_0_BME680_RH',
 'ES_0_BME680_TEMP',
 'ES_0_BME688_PRESS',
 'ES_0_BME688_RH',
 'ES_0_BME688_TEMP',( 'datetime', column is common for all the sensors.) and I have to calculate the data by using the above mentioned formulas for all these 25 sensors.

Comment: Yeah but we need an example of the data so we can propose a solution

Comment: You could use pandas, and import the content of the excel file with pandas.read_excel https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: @DataSciRookie Maybe data is private. I think it is self explanatory. He has a table in excel with colum names and numbers, and he has to do row by row calculations.

Comment: "column names of the 1st sensor"datetime-ES_0_BME680_RH-ES_0_BME680_TEMP-ES_0_BME688_RH-ES_0_BME688_TEMP
 
(data below those columns) 1st row-26.04.2022-10:53:02  AM -27.200001 -27.200001-31-26.9
2nd row-26.04.2022-11:53:02  AM -28.6-27.200001-32.799999-26.9      [Just used"-" to differentiate the values]

Comment: @deeksha are you sure for LN the formula ? how can you have LN=LN...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

d = {'datetime': ["26.04.2022-10:53:02 AM", "26.04.2022-11:53:02 AM"],
     'ES_0_BME680_RH': [-27.200001, -28.6],
    'ES_0_BME680_TEMP': [ -27.200001, -27.200001],
     'ES_0_BME688_RH': [-31, -32.799999],
    'ES_0_BME688_TEMP': [-26.9, -26.9]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['ph20']=611.2*np.exp((17.625*df[['ES_0_BME680_TEMP']])/(243.12+df[['ES_0_BME680_TEMP']]))
df['aH']=(df['ES_0_BME680_RH'] /100)*(df['ph20']/(461.52*(df['ES_0_BME680_TEMP']+273.15)))*1000
df['LN']=(((df['aH']/1000)*461.52*(df['ES_0_BME680_TEMP']+273.15))/(0.5*611.2))
df['T_tar']=(df['LN']*243.12)/(17.625-df['LN'])
df
```

Output :
[image]

Comment: yes, LN()"this is jus the name of the variable but I can name something else also"=LN(((........)))"this is the function to perform for log values in excel. I have tried the above code by altering{  d = pd.read_excel('FILENAME')
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)  } and the same code below. But I got this error "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' " @DataSciRookie

Comment: @deeksha because I guess your columns are not integer or float that's why

Comment: @deeksha   you can simply to pd.to_numeric(df['ES_0_BME680_RH'], errors='coerce') (for the four of them except the datetime. And then drop the lines which contains NaN and apply my solution

Comment: thank you. I tried your solution and it worked for the 0th sensor(namely ES_0_BME680_RH, ES_0_BME688_RH). But the tasks is that there are 25 sensors(differing like ES_1,ES_2 etc). I want todo same calculations for all those columns and plot graphs for its output new columns.

Comment: @deeksha if the solution worked for your specific question, you can accept the solution. If you want to update your question or create a new create for you need with the 25 sensors you can also. It's easy to put in a loop if it's the same formulas but different columns (different sensors as input)